# Does a higher integer value for priority weight in Airflow have a higher priority?

Tags: airflow-2.x

Does a higher integer value for priority weight in Airflow have a higher priority?

Example:

- Dag 1: Priority weight = 1
- Dag 2: Priority weight = 2

Which Dag has a higher priority and is executed first?

Airflow v2.0.2

Thank you

Reference:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/priority-weight.html